# Combining Sympy with scipy.optimize.least_squares

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to calculate the value of the variables *D* and *theta* for which the function E attains its minimum value.

`E = sqrt(x1-Dcos(theta)^2 + (y1-Dsin(theta)^2)) + sqrt(x2-2Dcos(theta)^2 + (y2-2Dsin(theta)^2)) + sqrt(x3-3Dcos(theta)^2 + (y3-3Dsin(theta)^2))`.

Here, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) are known. Now I calculate the partial derivatives of E wrt to D and theta and set them to zero. Now I have 2 equations and 2 unknowns, so theoretically this system should be exactly solvable. The only issue here is that this is highly non-linear. So analytical solutions are out of the question. I'm using Sympy here to calculate the partial derivatives and generate the equations to be used in least_squares from scipy.optimize. I do get a solution for D and theta but it doesn't make any physical sense. Furthermore, the cost value of least_squares is ~17, so my solutions are not very reliable, right? Could someone help me out here? Here's the code:

```
import sympy as sym
D, theta = sym.symbols("D, theta")
x1,x2,x3 = 9.0,22.0,24.0 
y1,y2,y3 = 14.0,14.0,14.0

E = ((x1-D*sym.cos(theta))**2 + (y1-D*sym.sin(theta))**2)**0.5 + ((x2-2*D*sym.cos(theta))**2 + (y2-2*D*sym.sin(theta))**2)**0.5 + ((x3-3*D*sym.cos(theta))**2 + (y3-3*D*sym.sin(theta))**2)**0.5

gradient = sym.derive_by_array(E, (D, theta))

from scipy.optimize import least_squares as ls
grad = sym.lambdify((D, theta), gradient)
A = ls(lambda v: grad(v[0],v[1]), (8,0), bounds=([0, -22.5*np.pi/180], [12, 22.5*np.pi/180]))  #theta should be between -22.5 degree and 22.5 degree and D should be between 0 and 12 but ideally not 0.
D2, theta2 = A.x # 0.04561884938833529 -0.3926990816987241
```

I should also mention that calculating *D* and *theta* is part of a problem that involves fitting a line through (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), and (13,2). D is the distance between (13,2) and the first point closest to (x1,y1) on the fitted line, 2D is similarly the distance between (13,2) and the second point closest to (x2,y2), and so on. This analysis has to be done over all the gridpoints on a lat-lon grid of size (21,69). All alternate suggestions to solve this problem are also welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to approximate the sequence `9, 22, 24` with an equidistant sequence like `11,18,25`. This does not have a good fit, so a large residual value is reasonable.

```
Doing the least square sum manually gives 

(a-d-9)^2 + (a-22)^2 + (a+d-24)^2 = 3*a^2 +2*d^2 - 110*a - 30*d +const

so the optimum is at a = 55/3 = 18+1/3 and d = 15/2 = 7+1/2
```

---

On a second glance, you try to minimize the sum of norms, that is, the sum of distances from points on a line parallel to the `x` axis to points equidistant on a line through the origin. You can do that without doing any least-squares gradient optimization (which is a strange idea anyway, why not just find the zero location of the gradient with `fsolve`?)

```
x = np.array([ 9.0,22.0,24.0]) 
y = np.array([14.0,14.0,14.0])
K = 1+np.arange(len(x))

target = lambda X,Y: sum(np.hypot(x-K*X, y-K*Y))

from scipy.optimize import fmin, minimize

#U = fmin(lambda u: target(*u), [4,4])
U = minimize(lambda u: target(*u), [4,4])
print(U)
X,Y = U.x
print(X,Y, np.hypot(X,Y), np.arctan2(Y,X))
K = np.arange(1+len(x))
plt.plot(x,y,'o', ms=8); plt.plot(K*X,K*Y, '-s', ms=4); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

with the results

```
fmin:
-----
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 16.987937
         Iterations: 49
         Function evaluations: 92

minimize:
---------
      fun: 16.987921401556633
 hess_inv: array([[2.72893764e-08, 6.01803467e-08],
       [6.01803467e-08, 1.53257534e-07]])
      jac: array([ 1.29665709, -0.08849001])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 740
      nit: 29
     njev: 182
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([8.        , 4.66666667])

X: 8.000000, Y: 4.666667, 
D: 9.261629, theta:  0.5280744
```

[image]

Comment: yes you got it right. In general, the points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) change. So only way to generalize this problem is by defining D and theta as the variables, which is why I need to calculate them. In the example given here, I know the answer is wrong because I get the wrong answer for theta. I would want theta to be close to zero degrees. Or rather if y1,y2,y3 remain the same then logically theta has to be zero. But I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: could you tell me why the line goes through (0,0) in the graph? It should go through (13,2). (13,2) is the starting point or rather that's from where 'D' is measured.